# Error en consulta sql fetchAll()

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un trozo de código que debería mostrar resultados de una consulta `sql` a una tabla, pero al hacer la consulta me sale el error

**Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean in /home/public_html/app/php/con-top-header.php:32 Stack trace: #0 /home/public_html/app/index.php(1): include() #1 {main} thrown in /home/public_html/app/php/con-top-header.php on line 32**

He de decir que tengo varias consultas creadas de la misma forma y no tengo ningun problema, ni con la variable `$conn` ni con `$u_e_id_show`

```html
<?php foreach ($assign_rows as $row) { ?>
   <option value="1"><?php echo $row['u_nombre']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

`

```html
// Extraer datos de usuarios si el ID de empresa coincide con el usuario
$assign_sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE u_empresaID='$u_e_id_show' ORDER BY id DESC";
$assign_result = $conn->query($assign_sql);
$assign_rows = $assign_result->fetchAll();
```

Y aquí el archivo de `conexion`

```html
<?php
function dbConnect (){
  $conn = null;
  $host = '*******';
  $db =  '*******';
  $user = '*******';
  $pwd =  '*******';
 try {
     $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $user, $pwd);

 }
 catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Excepción capturada: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
     exit;
 }
 return $conn;
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: Creo que el error no lo tienes en el foreach, sino en $assign_rows = $assign_result->fetchAll();

Comment: Si, he probado a quitar el foreach y igue sin funcionar

Comment: El problema es que `$assign_result` seguramente es `FALSE` debido a algún error. Puedes cambiar a esto: `if ($assign_result) { $assign_rows = $assign_result->fetchAll(); } else { echo $$assign_rows->errorInfo()[2]; }` Ahí te imprimirá el mensaje de error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`query()` devuelve un objeto PDOStatement (los datos obtenidos en la consulta podríamos decir) o `FALSE` si ocurre algún error. Por tanto, esa posibilidad debería ser controlada en el código.

Por ejemplo aquí evaluamos el estado, asignando a la variable los datos o bien un mensaje de error (que podría ser un array con una clave error en el caso de que estés trabajando con una API o una llamada asíncrona desde el cliente).

```
$assign_sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE u_empresaID='$u_e_id_show' ORDER BY id DESC";
if ($assign_result = $conn->query($assign_sql) ) {
    $assign_rows = $assign_result->fetchAll();
    #Leer aquí mismo los datos a pasarlos a otro sitio 
} else {
    echo "Hubo un error :". $conn->errorInfo()[2];
    #Aquí se puede crear un objeto con mensaje de error si se necesita
}
```

---

### Blindar el código contra ataques maliciosos

Debo decir que tu código es vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. No deberías nunca pasar variables en las consultas directamente. Para estos casos se recomienda usar consultas preparadas.

```
$assign_sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE u_empresaID=? ORDER BY id DESC";
if ( $stmt=$conn->prepare($assign_sql) ) {
    $stmt->execute( array($u_e_id_show) );
    $assign_rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    #Leer aquí mismo los datos a pasarlos a otro sitio 
} else {
    echo "Hubo un error :". $conn->errorInfo()[2];
    #Aquí se puede crear un objeto con mensaje de error si se necesita
}
```

Aquí básicamente se prepara la consulta sustituyendo el dato en sí por un marcador `?` y el dato se pasa en forma de array en el `execute`. Todo esto está explicado con detalle en el Manual de PHP y en varias preguntas de este mismo sitio.